# How to read last word or latest word in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am making a Source code Editor using JtextArea.In that I want to do the following task." While user typing on Editor window(JtextArea),each and every time the updated text(last word) should compare with the set of words in the database, if it matches any one of the word then the definition will be open in new popup frame."
My coding is like following

```
String str = textarea.getText();
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
        String stm="select url from pingatabl where functn=?";
        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(stm);
        st.setString(1, str);
         //Excuting Query
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
        String s = rs.getString(1);
        //Sets Records in frame
        JFrame fm = new JFrame();
        fm.setVisible(true);
        fm.setSize(500,750);
        JEditorPane jm = new JEditorPane();
        fm.add(jm);
        jm.setPage(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(s));
```

In the above coding `String str = textarea.getText();` reads all the text in the textarea.. but i need to get last word only. How can i get latest word from JTextArea..

Comment: Use a `DocumentListener` to monitor changes to the underlying `Document`, as you detect a "word" boundary, start a look up (preferably in the background)

Comment: You could also split the text and get the last word from the string . my two cents if it makes sense

Comment: I have tried that too..Coding is                                                                  "Document doc= jtextarea.getDocument();                                                         String str=doc.gettext(doc.getLength()-1,1);" but it reads only last character.

Comment: if i use getText().split("\n"); means it gets whole text without a space..

Comment: @Leks For the last word use this: `String str = jtextarea.getText(); str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(' ')+1, str.length());` but it does not help you, if the user types soemthing at the beginnig of the text, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code block if you want to get the last word in the testarea

```
String[] wordsArray = textarea.getText().split("\\s+");
String lastWord = wordsArray[wordsArray.length - 1];
```

But if you want to get the last updated word then you have to use a Listener for that.
Check on `DocumentListener` and `DocumentEvent` 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentEvent.html

Comment: Thank you so much. I need this only. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `DocumentListener` to monitor for changes to the text component and use `javax.swing.text.Utilities` to calculate the start/end index of the word in the `Document`, from which you can the extract the result

[image: The Last Word]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.Utilities;

public class TheLastWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TheLastWord();
    }

    public TheLastWord() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 20);
            add(new JScrollPane(ta));
            JLabel lastWord = new JLabel("...");
            add(lastWord, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            ta.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    checkLastWord();
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    checkLastWord();
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    checkLastWord();
                }

                protected void checkLastWord() {
                    try {
                        int start = Utilities.getWordStart(ta, ta.getCaretPosition());
                        int end = Utilities.getWordEnd(ta, ta.getCaretPosition());
                        String text = ta.getDocument().getText(start, end - start);
                        lastWord.setText(text);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the last line in your JEditorPane, split the text in the editor on \n as shown below:

```
String text = editor.getText();

String[] lines = text.split("\n");
```

String lastLine = lines[lines.length-1];
System.out.println("Last line: " + lastLine);

Similarly, to get the last word, split the last line on space.

Comment: *" While user typing on Editor "*

Answer (score 0):

Here a code of method that returns the last word of a text

```
   public static String getLastWord(String s) {
    int endOfLine = s.length() - 1;
    boolean start = false;
    while (!start && endOfLine >= 0) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(s.charAt(endOfLine))) {
            endOfLine--;
        } else {
            start = true;
        }
    }
    final StringBuilder lastWord = new StringBuilder("");
    while (start && endOfLine >= 0) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(s.charAt(endOfLine))) {
            start = false;
        } else {
            lastWord.insert(0, s.charAt(endOfLine));
            endOfLine--;
        }
    }
    return lastWord.toString();

}
```

Comment: You can use Character.isLetterOrDigit(char r) if your word contains digitis

Comment: Seriously?  What's wrong with just using `String#lastIndexOf` to find the last white space and `String#substring` to get the last portion of the text?

Comment: Example : what is the last word of "What's" ? I think it is "s" and not "What's" ? it depends how do you define the last word ? Check also when there is only one word on your text or your text ends with espace ;) or "\n"

Comment: Okay, even if you have `What's` coming out as the "last" word from `indexOf` and `substring`, you could still use `indexOf` and `substring` again when you detect the word `'` ... all the loops just seem like over kill to me.  I'm sure you could even hobble together a regular expression :P

Comment: I see, in this case you have to think also about other caracter such as "\n" and "\t" .. and when your text ends with white space